# How does the VS editor know about controls in the XAML part

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It almost seems like magic that as soon as I enter a control with a *Name="myControl"* attribute to the XAML code of a window, the editor of Visual Studio knows about the corresponding member variable in the code-behind. So the editor and intellisense seem to scan the XAML code at design time in order to anticipate which member variables the framework will create at runtime for the controls of a window. What exactly goes on behind the scenes for this to work? My guess is that VS uses the System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector interface at design time to find out about the properties of a window class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with window/user control `xaml` in designer you are changing both: `xaml` and designer generated `cs` (look inside `obj` folder, there are `WindowName.g.cs` and `WindowName.g.i.cs`).

As soon as you add `x:Name` it will appears as a property in designer generated `cs`. Then you (or *Intellisense*) is able to use it when you are editing `xaml.cs`.

Comment: That was exactly the information I was looking for.